# External DVD writer not detected in xfburn

Tags: dvd

I have an external dvd writer (brand: Buffalo) and it is not detected in xfburn.

How do I solve this ?

```
$ udevadm info --name=/dev/sr1 --query=all

P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sr1
N: sr1
S: cdrom1
S: cdrw1
S: disk/by-id/usb-BUFFALO_Optical_Drive_303042323932363132303730
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
S: dvd1
S: dvdrw1
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/cdrom1 /dev/cdrw1 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-BUFFALO_Optical_Drive_303042323932363132303730 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 /dev/dvd1 /dev/dvdrw1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sr1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sr1
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: GENERATED=1
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_CDROM=1
E: ID_CDROM_CD=1
E: ID_CDROM_CD_R=1
E: ID_CDROM_CD_RW=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_PLUS_R=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_PLUS_RW=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_PLUS_R_DL=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_R=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_RAM=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_RW=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD_R=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_SESSION_COUNT=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_SESSION_NEXT=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_STATE=blank
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_TRACK_COUNT=1
E: ID_CDROM_MRW=1
E: ID_CDROM_MRW_W=1
E: ID_MODEL=Optical_Drive
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Optical\x20Drive
E: ID_MODEL_ID=01dc
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_7-usb-0_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_REVISION=0200
E: ID_SERIAL=BUFFALO_Optical_Drive_303042323932363132303730
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=303042323932363132303730
E: ID_TYPE=floppy
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080550:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=BUFFALO
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=BUFFALO
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0411
E: MAJOR=11
E: MINOR=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: TAGS=:udev-acl:
E: UDEV_LOG=3
E: UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=25401156756
```

Answer (score 3):

From the udev info we can see that the device is detected as `ID_TYPE=floppy`.

xfburn ignores devices which are not `ID_TYPE=cd`.

So to solve this

1. edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules` as root
2. add a new line `SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="xxxxxxx", ENV{ID_TYPE}="cd", ENV{GENERATED}="1"`
3. replace `"xxxxxxx"` with the serial number of your device from the above lines
4. save and restart xfburn, and also unplug and replug the device.

also refer this forum post (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2012070)

Comment: My system doesn't have that rules file already, only the rules.d folder but it's empty... What's confusing me is that lshw, dmesg (when plugging in/out) show scsi CD/DVD info on them, there are multiple 'ID_CDROM_CD_R=1' lines in the output of 'udevadmn info' but instead of type being floppy, mine says 'generic' but still not reading in burning software.